# How do I Identify the validator causing failure when using DataAnnotations on MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I m using data annotations for validation on MVC 4.
Several validation expressions are applied on each Model property and form is validated on client side.

Is it possible to identify the expression that indicated failure using javascript?
For ex, if I have a requiredField and regex validator on a property, I should be able to tell the property evaluated to false from regex expression.

I do not want to infer it from validation messages as these might be changed (and more-over we are supporting multiple languages) !!

Comment: Maby i didn't undestand you, but `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` helper doesn't solve your problem? If there if multiple validators it shows message only for one that couse the problem.

Comment: Its not possible using javascipt. Inspect the html of the element - it will include a series of `data-val-*` attributes. When the property is validated (unobtrusive validation), the `data-val-*` attributes are tested in order and a message is displayed for the **first** one that fails. It does not continue to check other conditions. You can however inspect `ModelState` on the server to get all errors for a property.